# How do I pass a variable(Date) as a parameter in python into SQL?

Tags: python

Could you please guide me how do I can pass a variable(date) as a parameter to the below SQL (Postgre SQL database) in a python script ?

```
last_Execution_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   researcherid,
   username,
   firstname,                                                      
   lastname,                                                         
FROM researcher r
  INNER JOIN principals p ON p.researcherid = r.researcherid  
WHERE r.lastmodifieddate > 'last_Execution_date'
```

I need to pass the `last_Execution_date` as a parameter to the above SQL statement. Could somebody please tell me the correct syntax? I am not quite sure whether is it possible to pass the outside variable as a parameter because the SQL statement runs on the database and returns the data.

Comment: Fixed up grammar, a couple of spelling inconsistencies, and punctuation for nicer reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:
Say:

```
  last_Execution_date = datetime.datetime.now()<br>
```

then,

```
cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT researcherid , username, firstname,
lastname,FROM researcher r INNER JOIN principals p 
ON p.researcherid = r.researcherid 
WHERE r.lastmodifieddate > %s',last_Execution_date)
```

Comment: I think its not taking last_execution_date as a parameter

Comment: this is the error : TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: try this : 
cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT researcherid , username, firstname,
lastname,FROM researcher r INNER JOIN principals p 
ON p.researcherid = r.researcherid 
WHERE r.lastmodifieddate > '{}' '.format(last_Execution_date))

Comment: Thanks Ajay , its working now . i have made a small change .  '{0}' '.format(last_Execution_date)) . Thanks for your help .

Comment: would you mind accepting the answer and make your edit in my answer, i'll approve that. :D